# My Sql Sys_exec works but nothing happens

Tags: mysql, user-defined-functions

i have this problem in my MySql Trigger.
When my trigger fires , nothing happens , sys_exec wont show anything. heres the trigger code :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `TrigTest` AFTER UPDATE ON `event` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DECLARE cmd CHAR(255);
DECLARE result int(10);
SET cmd = CONCAT("C:\Users\Mortadha\Documents\tst.c");
SET result = sys_exec(cmd);
END
```

the tst.c file is just a hello world file.
( all i want is for the trigger to excute my c code when updating a table )

Comment: **tst.c** look like a text file. you must give a executables file

Comment: i used executables as well , doesnt work either